# Is there place in BIOS which can survive warm reset?

Tags: x86, low-level, bios, osdev

Is there any place (except HDD, Floppy and etc.) where I can store a few bytes of information and read them back after warm CPU reset?

I've tried to use *BIOS Data Area* (in particular: `0x0040:0x00F0 - Inter-application communication area`), but this area is filled with zeroes upon reset, so my information is lost.

Is there any other place which is not cleared during reset?

Comment: If I was feeling abusive, I'd say to store the data in the real-time clock. That gives you *very* few bits to play with, but will definitely survive a reset.

Comment: Thanks, nneonneo. Actually it is my "fallback" idea, to use RTC. But I still hope to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine state is undefined after a reset (cold or warm), so the short answer is no.

However, you may abuse some hardware, **although not reliable**, to store values when reset.

- Display ram, some card however do clear the memory.
- MSRs, this however is model specific
- PCI registers - the BAR seems to be unchanged upon reset for some card.

Again, all of the above is not reliable. Not surprise, to store value persistent across reset, you need persistent storage, i.e. disk, remote servers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small amount of storage reserved for CMOS, where you can store a few bytes, the address of the register address from 0 to 255 is specified via port 70h, the data are written to port 71h, range 34Н-3FH is safe to store your own data. First you write the register address, then you write the data. When reading, you write the register address and read the data. The size of the registers is 1 byte.